# Count number of ids for each id in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables. One is Booking and other is Course. Course can have many Bookings. 
I want to count number of Bookings for each Course and pass that to ViewBag. So I want to count how many users applied for each Course.

This line counts total number o Bookings but I cant figure out how to do that for each Course.

```
ViewBag.Counter = db.Bookings.Count();
```

This line gets all the courses to my Index page.

```
 IEnumerable<Course> courses = cr.GetCourses();
        return View(courses.ToList());
```

And this is controller that is doing the work. I tried with 2 foreach loops but cant get it to work.

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Booking booking = new Booking();
        Course course = new Course();
        List<Course> listCourses = new List<Course>();
        List<Booking> bookings = new List<Booking>();

        foreach (var item in listCourses)
        {
            int id = course.CourseId;

            foreach (var item1 in bookings)
            {
                ViewBag.Counter = db.Bookings.Where(x => x.CourseId == id).Count();
            }
        }
        IEnumerable<Course> courses = cr.GetCourses();
        return View(courses.ToList());
    }
```

I expect to get a number of users that applied for each course that is listed on my index page. I got no exceptions or errors and nothing shows up in my view. When I use `ViewBag.Counter = db.Bookings.Count();` I get a total number of users that applied for all avaliable courses. Model on the view is Course model which is in relation with Booking with one to many relation.

This is the View for my ActionResult.

```
@model IEnumerable<Entities.Course>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "AlgebraSchoolApp";
}

<h2>Dobrodošli!</h2>
<p>
Da bi se prijavili na neki od naših tečajeva kliknite na link prijave: 
<button>
    @Html.ActionLink("Prijava","Create","Booking")
</button>
</p>

<h2> Svi tečajevi</h2>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CourseName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("Broj polaznika")
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @ViewBag.Counter
        </td>
    </tr>
}


</table>

<h2>Slobodni tečajevi</h2>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CourseName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
    </th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.Full == false))
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Only the last two lines of the `Index` method actually do anything. The loops are enumerating over empty collections, while the `booking` and `course` variables are never used.

Comment: Seems like you could just use a `GroupBy` on the bookings: `db.Bookings.GroupBy(b => b.CourseId)` and then you'll have a count for each course (where the group key is the course id, if you need to correlate them).

Comment: Thanks for the replys! 
So I managed to count with foreach loop like this 
 
`foreach (var item in listCourses)
            {
                ViewBag.Counter = db.Bookings.Where(b => b.CourseId == item.CourseId).Count();
            }`
but still I dont get the right results. Lets say one class has 2 students and other 1. My code count only one class and shows it on both positions on my list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `ViewBag.Counter` is showing the same result for all courses is because it is being overwritten each time with `ViewBag.Counter = db.Bookings.Where(x => x.CourseId == id).Count();`.

If i have understood your issue this can be fixed by creating a new view model to store the required information for a course and return this to your view. EG:

```
public class CourseViewModel 
{
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //etc
    public int BookingCount { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var courses = cr.GetCourses();
    var courseViewModels= new List<CourseViewModel>();
    foreach (var course in courses )
    {
        var bookingCount = db.Bookings.Where(x => x.CourseId == course.CourseId).Count();
        courseViewModels.Add(new CourseViewModel{
            CourseName = course.CourseName, //Add all the vm properties
            BookingCount = bookingCount
        });
    }

    return View(courseViewModels);
}
```

In the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<CourseViewModel>
@/*...*/
@foreach (var item in Model)

{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookingCount )
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it works as I wanted. I found this before but i Thought I can make this work without another model. Is this the best practice for solwing thingslike this? Lets say an admin picks which user will be emloyed and the easiest way is to add a model from which that will be done?

Comment: @brika28 Yes, it is best practice to pass down a seperate view model instead of the context classes. It also allows you to add properties such as `BookingCount` which are related to a `Course` but are not stored in the database or remove things that are not required in the razor code. Along with other benefits such as making the code easier to maintain.